# Загрузка данных с 10 файлов Excel в Python

Tags: python, excel

Программа, должна считывать средний обменный курс за 2011-2020 годы с 10 файлов excel и рассчитывать:

- Обменный курс EUR / USD на основе котировки злотого: EURO / USD =
  (EURO / PLN) / (USD / PLN)
- Среднее значение обменных курсов для
  каждой валюты (включая евродоллар)
- Самый высокий курс обмена злотого
  по отношению к любой валюте
- Самый низкий курс обмена злотого по
  отношению к любой валюте
- Разницу между самым высоким и самым низким
  обменным курсом злотого.
- Мера волатильности (отношение разницы к
  самому высокому обменному курсу) злотого по отношению к каждой
  валюте.
- Самую маленькую и самую большую меру вариации

Можно ли загрузить данные одновременно с 10 файлов і одновременно вычислить все для всех файлов? Проблема в том, что есть 37 столбцов и 241 строчка с цифрами во всех 10 файлах.
Ниже уместила скрин с примером файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
> import os 
> import pandas as pd 
> os.getcwd() 
> from openpyxl import load_workbook 
> kurs2020 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2020.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2019 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2019.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2018 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2018.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2017 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2017.xlsx'sheet_name = 0)
> kurs2016 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2016.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2015 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2015.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2014 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2014.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2013 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2013.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2012 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2012.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kurs2011 = load_workbook(filename ='kurs2011.xlsx'sheet_name = 0) 
> kursy = kurs2020.append(kurs2019)(kurs2018)(kurs2017)(kurs2016)(kurs2015 (kurs2014)(kurs2013)(kurs2012)(kurs2011)
> for e,d in kursy:
>         e = ['I3':'I241'].value
>         d=['C3':'C241'].value
>         ed = e/d
>         print (ed)
>     for k in ['A3':'A241'],['B3':'B241'],['C3':'C241'],['D3':'D241'],['E3':'E241'],['F3':'F241'],['G3':'G241'],['H3':'H241'],['I3':'I241'],['J3':'J24'1],['K3':'K241'],['L3':'L241'],['M3':'M241'],['O3':'O241'],['P3':'P241'],['Q3':'Q241'],['R3':'R241'],['S3':'S241'],['T3':'T241'],['U3':'U241'],['V3':'V241'],['W3':'W241'],['X3':'X241'],['Y3':'Y241'],['Z3':'Z241']:
>         v=k.value
>         średnie=v/238
>         minimum=min(v)
>         maksimum=max(v)
>         różnica=maksimum-minimum
>         zmiennośc=róznica*maksimum
>         minimzmien=min(zmienność)
>         makszmien=max(zmienność)
>         
>         
>         print(średnie)
>         print(minimum)
>         print(maximum)
>         print(różnica)
>         print(zmienność)
>         print(minimzmien)
>         print(makszmien)
```

---

Comment: Выглядит страшно. Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону pandas - это библиотека для работы с массивами данных, в том числе и для данных их Excel. Да и скрин в вопросе крайне низкого качества. Не видно ничего

Answer (score 0):

Можно загрузить в один датафрейм
Вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe
и работать с Pandas используя функции библиотеки